# How to fetch unread email using javax.mail pop3 from outlook

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, office365, email-attachments, pop3

I am trying to fetch unread email from Inbox(**Outlook.office365.com**) and also copy the read message to another folder. But I am getting some of the following issues.

1. Email is being re-read again, even if we mark the email as being
   read programmatically.
2. Unable to copy an email to another folder even when we open the Inbox is RW(Read&Write) mode.

Attached my code as well.

```
package com.xyz.mail;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class ReadEmail {

    private static final String TRUE = "true";
    private static final String MAIL_POP3_HOST = "mail.pop3.host";
    private static final String MAIL_POP3_PORT = "mail.pop3.port";
    private static final String MAIL_POP3_STARTTLS_ENABLE = "mail.pop3.starttls.enable";
    private static final String MAIL_FOLDER_INBOX = "INBOX";

    public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user, String password) throws Exception {

        Store store = null;
        Folder emailFolder = null;
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(MAIL_POP3_HOST, host);
            properties.put(MAIL_POP3_PORT, "995");
            properties.put(MAIL_POP3_STARTTLS_ENABLE, TRUE);
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            store = emailSession.getStore(storeType);

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            emailFolder = store.getFolder(MAIL_FOLDER_INBOX);
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
            if (messages.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("No new messages found.");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0, len = messages.length; i < len; i++) {
                    Message message = messages[i];

                    boolean hasAttachments = hasAttachments(message);
                    if (hasAttachments) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "Email #" + (i + 1) + " with subject " + message.getSubject() + " has attachments.");
                        readAttachment(message);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Email #" + (i + 1) + " with subject " + message.getSubject()
                                + " does not have any attachments.");
                        continue;
                    }

                    Folder copyFolder = store.getFolder("copyData");
                    if (copyFolder.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("copy messages...");
                        copyFolder.copyMessages(messages, emailFolder);
                        message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String host = "outlook.office365.com";
        String username = "emailtest@xyz.com";
        String password = "passw0rd{}";
        String mailStoreType = "pop3s";

        check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

    }

    private static boolean hasAttachments(Message msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg.isMimeType("multipart/mixed")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            if (mp.getCount() > 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void readAttachment(Message message) throws Exception {

        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                String destFilePath = "/home/user/Documents/" + part.getFileName();
                System.out.println("Email attachement ---- " + destFilePath);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);
                InputStream input = part.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int byteRead;
                while ((byteRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                }
                output.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How to I fetch only unread email and copy the email to another folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the protocal to imap and change the prot respecitvely ..using pop3 we can access only inbox that is the reason why you are unable to copy the mail to another folder

Comment: Yes, use imap, not pop3, and be sure to fix any of these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).